# Azure Media Services with AAD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've been spending hours trying to generate an access token to use the Azure Media Service API via Service principal authentication.

I'd like to use this within a node application however I am yet to be able to generate the required token using Postman, with the steps documented in [this blog post](http://blog.chohanwu.com/2017/01/azure-media-service-nodejs-sdk-and-rest.html). The official MS docs have not been any more help that this blogpost.

This is the error message I'm receiving

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "ACS90004: The request is not properly formatted.\r\nTrace ID: 73ba5bee-b7d2-4d2c-8583-3c673baf4684\r\nCorrelation ID: ddd08f52-608c-4177-ad2f-112381cffe56\r\nTimestamp: 2017-12-07 08:58:32Z"
}
```

From this POST request

Url: https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13

Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net
Content-Length:120
Expect:100-Continue
Connection:Keep-Alive
Accept:application/json
```

Body:

```
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:urn:WindowsAzureMediaServices
client_id:{{aad app id}}
client_secret:{{key generated in aad app}}
```

Any help here or good documentation links would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the way detailed in the question is old, and deprecated.

This tutorial has allowed me to connect when using `https://rest.media.azure.net` as the resource body parameter

http://blog.jongallant.com/2017/03/azure-active-directory-access-tokens-postman/